# How to use font awesome as an icon in leaflet instead of marker

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, font-awesome

In this code, I was using `data[key].category` to indicate related Icon as the marker. but I want to replace it with font-awesome icons to make it light-weight on runtime in some places may load over tens of icons as the markers

```
var Cofee= Leaflet.icon({
      iconUrl: '/img/Coffee.png',
      shadowUrl: '/img/pale-shadow.png',
      iconSize: [34, 49], 
      shadowSize: [49, 49],
      iconAnchor: [5, 62],
      shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
      popupAnchor: [12, -30]
});
var Store= Leaflet.icon({
      iconUrl: '/img/Store.png',
      shadowUrl: '/img/pale-shadow.png',
      iconSize: [34, 49], 
      shadowSize: [49, 49],
      iconAnchor: [5, 62],
      shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
      popupAnchor: [12, -30]
});
..
..
..

this.Getlatlng(currentlatlng, 9000).then(data => {
    for (var key in data) {
        Leaflet.marker(data[key].location, { icon: data[key].category })      
         .addTo(this.map).bindPopup('<h4>'+data[key].caption+'</h4>');
          markers.push([data[key].location.lat,data[key].location.lng]);
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use font-awesome icons instead of built-in marker icons like this:

```
const fontAwesomeIcon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-4x"></i>',
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    className: 'myDivIcon'
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09],{ icon:  fontAwesomeIcon}).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
```

```js
const map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 8);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

const fontAwesomeIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-4x"></i>',
  iconSize: [20, 20],
  className: 'myDivIcon'
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {
    icon: fontAwesomeIcon
  }).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.leaflet-popup-close-button {
  display: none;
}

.myDivIcon {
  text-align: center;
  /* Horizontally center the text (icon) */
  line-height: 20px;
  /* Vertically center the text (icon) */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working for `fa-map-marker` but for others, its int working. I tried `fa` ,`fab` and `fas` for example : `<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>` this is not.

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/9aheo6xb/ You should not use `fas` but `fa` class for font-awesome version 4.7.0.

Comment: Can the color be specified?

Comment: I have issues with a offset. Tip of marker is not on line starting point. => How do correctly set iconAnchor?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I had to adjust the anchors like this.
```const fontAwesomeIcon = L.divIcon({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-3x"></i>',
    iconSize: [27, 36],
    iconAnchor: [13.5, 36],
    popupAnchor: [0, -36],
    className: 'myDivIcon'
});```

Answer (score 2):

kboul's answer is a really nice simple solution that worked for me. Furthermore...here is how I then applied the code to the use of geojson point data.  In this case, I am using the geojson in an overlay map.

```
var clinics = L.geoJson(clinicData, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, { icon: fontAwesomeIcon });
  },
});
```